# Radiation originates due to emission by matter but its transport does not require any matter... Expand?

Tags: radiation, matter

excerpt from text: Radiation originates due to emission by matter and that its subsequent transport does not require the presence of any matter.

Can someone expand on this. This is quite mind-blowing

Answer (score 1):

For example, sunlight travels through near-vacuum between Sun and Earth. It could easily do so through a perfect vacuum.

Light from the Andromeda galaxy travels through the emptiness of intergalactic space to get to us.

Electromagnetic waves are ripples in the electromagnetic field. They can be caused by matter but they require no matter to propagate. All they need is the electromagnetic field, and it is already everywhere in the universe.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a bomb exploding in vacuum. Do the pieces need a medium  to travel according to the  velocity given by the explosion?

Radiation is of two kinds, electromagnetic, or the so called alpha and beta radiation which are composed of massive particles. The kinematics is the same as with an explosion.

In the [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation) they include in the term radiation the transport of sound through a medium, but I believe your source is talking of nuclear and particle physics.

Comment: The pieces of the bomb are matter, so it seems a bit awkward to consider whether they need matter to travel.

Comment: @electronpusher corrected, thanks